# Print columns that start with a specific string

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
ID101     G    T     freq=.5     nonetype     ANC=.1     addinfor
ID102     A    T     freq=.3     ANC=.01    addinfor
ID102     A    T     freq=.01     type=1     ALT=0.022    ANC=.02    addinfor
```

As you can see, each line has a slightly different number of columns. I specifically want column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4 and the column that starts with `ANC=`

Desired output:

```
ID101     G    T     freq=.5     ANC=.1
ID102     A    T     freq=.3     ANC=.01
ID102     A    T     freq=.01    ANC=.02
```

I generally use the an awk command to parse files:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {print $1, $2, $3, $4}'
```

Is there an easy way to alter this command to work for situations like this?

I think something like this might work:

```
awk '{for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){if($j~/^ANC=/){print $j}}}'
```

However, how can I edit this to also print the first columns?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^ANC=/){a=$i}} print $1,$2,$3,$4,a}' file
```

---

- `for(...)` loops through all fields, starting with field 5 (`i=5`).

  - `if($i~/^ANC=/)` checks if the field starts with `ANC=`
  - `a=$i` if yes, set variable a to that value
- `print $1,$2,$3,$4,a` print fields 1-4 followed by whatever is stored in `a`.

---

Can be combined with `BEGIN {OFS="\t"}` of course.

Comment: what does the `i=5` do?

Comment: @stellar01 this starts the loop at field number 5.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `ANC=` column is always the second-to-last column (as in the example data):

```
$ awk '{ print $1, $2, $3, $(NF-1) }' data.in
ID101 G T ANC=.1
ID102 A T ANC=.01
ID102 A T ANC=.02
```

`NF` is the number of fields (columns) that `awk` splits each record (line) into.  `$(NF-1)` is the value of the second-to-last field.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pale '$"="\t", $_="@{[@F[0..3],         grep {   /^ANC=/ } @F[4..$#F]]}"' yourfile
perl -lane '$,="\t",          print @F[0..3], grep {   /^ANC=/ } @F[4..$#F]'    yourfile
perl -lane '($,,$a)=("\t",0), print grep { $a++ < 4 or /^ANC=/ } @F'            yourfile
```

## Brief

$, => `OFS` `@F[0..3]` => `$F[0] $F[1] $F[2] $F[4]`